# Passing a value between templates using flask.g

Tags: python, flask

Using Flask I have  page that is serving as a wait screen until a user places an RFID card on a reader. Once a card is placed on the reader, a `user` value is passed into the template and and then the user is automatically moved to another page. I need to capture the value (using as I understand flask.g) and pass it to this second page. Currently my Flask `views.py` looks like this:

```
@app.route('/activity', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def activity():
    user = g.user
    location = {'mspace': 'Central Library'} 
    return render_template('activity.html',
                            location = location,
                            user = user)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index(): 
    global checkCheck
    print "starting"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # print(request.data)
        checkCheck = True
        location = {'mspace': 'Central Library'} 
        user = {'nickname': request.args.get('name')}
        print "works!"
        print user['nickname']
        return render_template('index.html',
                    location = location,
                    user = user) 
    g.user = user
    return render_template('index.html', 
                            location = "test", 
                            user = 'user')
```

But when instead of rendering the second page after the card is placed I'm getting the error `AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'user'` - why isn't the second page recognizing the `g.user`?

Comment: You cannot use `g` to pass data between different requests; it is global only to the current request.

Comment: Also, you put the `g.user = user` line **after** the `return`, so it is never executed.

Comment: Hey Martijn - thanks for explaining that what should I use instead to store a variable that I can use across templates?

Comment: Use the session to store data across *requests*.

Comment: Hey Martijn - I actually started down that road after your first comment, but then found myself at a new impasse (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246357/passing-a-session-variable-between-templates-in-flask)