# Passing a session variable between Templates in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to assign a session variable in one Template and pass it to another, but I keep getting `KeyError: 'var'` error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. My views.py looks as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, session
from app import app
@app.route('/activity', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def activity():
    user = session['var']
    location = {'mspace': 'Central Library'} 
    return render_template('activity.html',
                            location = location,
                            user = user)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index(): 
    global checkCheck
    print "starting"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # print(request.data)
        checkCheck = True
        location = {'mspace': 'Central Library'} 
        user = {'nickname': request.args.get('name')}
        session['var'] = user
        # print user['nickname']
        print session['var']
        return render_template('index.html',
                    location = location,
                    user = user) 

    return render_template('index.html', 
                            location = "test", 
                            user = 'user')
```

and here's my activity.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ location['mspace'] }} - Makerspace </title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello, {{ user['nickname'] }} - what activity are you doing today:</h1>

      <form action="" method="">
        <h3> Choose your Activity</h3>
        <select name="activity"> 
            <option value='3dprinting'>3D Printing</option>
            <option value='Minecraft'>Minecraft</option>
            <option value='Arduino'>Arduino</option>
            <option value='Wearables'>Wearables</option>
        </select>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ location['mspace'] }} - Makerspace </title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello, {{ user['nickname'] }}!</h1>
    </body>

    <script>

    function httpGet(theUrl)
    {
               var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
               xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
               xmlHttp.send(null);
               return xmlHttp.responseText;
    }

    setInterval(checkFunc(), 1000);

    function checkFunc(){
        var json = httpGet("/getSignIn");
            console.log("yes!");
            obj = JSON.parse(json);
            console.log(obj.newCheckin);
            if(obj.newCheckin){
                window.location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:5000/activity");
            }
            else{
                setInterval(checkFunc(), 1000);
            }
    }

  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You only set the session variable when the request is a POST. You haven't shown the index template, but are you sure it has a POST?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure - it's waiting for information passed to it from an RFID reader, and I get the `print session['var']` in terminal so it is executing the `if request.method == 'POST':` code

Comment: Sessions require that your browser allows cookies. You do need to see if a new session was started perhaps, so use `user = session.get('var')` and `if user is None:` is going to be true if there was no such variable in the session.

Comment: Ok so I don't get `user:'none` in `print session['var']` I get the output `{'nickname': u'Dave'}` so the session is definitely starting

Comment: Try to save simple values in session not dicts: `session['var'] = request.args.get('name')` in your `index` handler and use `user = session.get('var')` in `activity` handler.

Comment: And also show your `index.html` form code.

Comment: Hi doru - I added the index.html and tried out what you suggested but session.get('var')` outputs None (and not 'Dave')

Comment: 1. Do you store a lot of other data in the session cookie? Client side cookies are limited in size and can lead to problems. 2. Are you running this in a parallel application? 3. Your last comment sounds suspicious. `print session['var']` contains the dictionary but `print session.get('var')` is `None`?

Comment: @Midnighter 1) Not really storing anything else at the moment, 2) What do you mean by a parallel application? 3) Well if I put `print session.get('var')` in `def index(): ` it outputs the same as `print session['var']` but when I do it in `def activity():` it outputs none

Comment: I don't see on your index page the use of the POST method.